# Unifi bridge to switch or ethernet

Tags: switch, wireless-bridge, ubiquiti

I have been trying to figure this out and can't seem to get it to work. What I'm wanting to do is create a switch on a stick using Unifi AC Pro's in bridge\mesh mode and extending the network onto that switch. Thinking layer 2 extension.

My setup is as follows, a bunch of vlans with the AP's (UAP-AC-PRO) setup on the management vlan in Unifi. I have been able to get the AP's to mesh but can't seem to get any traffic to pass across the bridge.

In my diagram below, I have the core side with the APs and my stick network meshed to it. I have tried connecting the AP into the switch, tried trunking the AP port and untagging vlans on the switch ports.

I have also tried connecting my laptop to port #2 on the AP but no traffic gets passed either, as i saw someone doing that on youtube but i don't think they were dealing with vlans.

VLAN 7 = Management network
VLAN 3 = Main wifi
VLAN 6 = Guest Wifi

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1PTF.png)

Any ideas or thoughts? Is this even possible?

Noticed that there is no network for the meshing AP, not sure if that has something to do with it?
[Unifi dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho6Vm.png)

Comment: What is your AP model   I have a Ubiquiti AP here (AC-Lite) which is a bit different than yours, but no mesh at all with mine.  Controller software looks similar to mine.

Comment: I have 2 UAP-AC-PRO's running on the cloudkey G2 plus controller latest versions.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot find that they support mesh and there is nothing about mesh in my Ubiquiti controller software (also latest version). So I do not know. Sorry.

Comment: I think (not at all certain) that you need a Ubiquiti mesh router for your needs. As noted, not certain.